# If $dx/dy =\sin(x)$ then is $dy/dx = 1/\sin(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \sin(x),$ then is $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$?

I'm trying to understand how to manipulate $dx$ and $dy$ quantities effectively.

Comment: If **Panny** walks ten times the speed of **Nanny**, then does **Nanny** walk one-tenth of the speed of **Panny**?

Comment: @Venus Could you please provide that link for everyone's benefit? An obvious place to expect an admonishment about "too much vertical space" would be in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144 where I see a request to minimize vertical space in _titles_, but nothing like that for the question itself.

Comment: Stop defacing this question. I'm removing unrelated comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the chain rule (assuming all quantities exist and make sense):

$$\dfrac {\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\dfrac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac {\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx} = 1$$

do you see how that answers your question?

edit: the OP asked when this works. This works if $y$ is invertible and the derivative isn't $0$. If $y$ is not invertible, then $x$ might still implicitly define a differentiable function of $y$ for some neighborhood of a point you're interested in.

Comment: Not really..... :) Where did sin(x) go?

Comment: Multiply your two equations together.

Comment: It works. :) But can I always do that? For any given $y = f(x)$?

Comment: edited my answer to explain when it works

Comment: @bodacydo looks like GFauPax answered your questions. If so, you should accept it so we know its been addressed.

Comment: Just to be clear for the OP: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sin x}$ as long as $\sin x\neq 0$. Of course $\frac{dx}{dy}=\sin x$ is defined for all real numbers $x$.